# Append new Arraylist in arrayadapter

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to append or add a new arraylist in an arrayadapter which is already  running. Means I want to retain its previous list and want to add more items through an another arraylist. How it will possible? Means suggest me the right solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this Link....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383330/how-to-combine-two-array-list-and-show-in-a-listview-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ArrayList.addAll();](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20E%3E%29)

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) usually help. Just add them.