# How to add items in two columns in Listview (Android)?

Tags: android, listview

I have worked in Listview, I have stored values in arraylist1 and arraylist2, then retrieve the value from arraylist1, arraylist2 and then insert these two arraylists values 
in each row, how? Please can any one help me?

Thanks

Example:

```
arraylist1 - 23/1/12
arraylist2 - welcome
```

These two values are inser in Listview

```
ListView - 23/1/12     welcome
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383330/how-to-combine-two-array-list-and-show-in-a-listview-in-android ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Multicolumn ListView in Android](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/). And add your arraylists values in

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Value1", arrayList1.get(0));
map.put("Value2", arrayList2.get(0));
mylist.add(map);
```

Comment: lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DocketCalc.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , mylist));

Comment: Yes, because, you need a give a resource id, which display those strings, If possible use the same adapter as provided in example link.